# Limit DatagridView column using DataTable jquery in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, datatables

I have following code in aspx page and its inherits from master page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.14/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.14/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntHeader" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntContent" runat="server">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
            <asp:GridView ID="gvState" runat="server" CssClass="gvdatatable" AutoGenerateColumns="true" >
                 <Columns>    
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Supplier_Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Supplier_Email" HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                 </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.gvdatatable').dataTable({});
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

My code behind is

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    clsSupplier objsupplier = new clsSupplier();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = objsupplier.GetAllSuppliers();
        gvState.DataSource = ds;
        gvState.DataBind();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.gvState.ShowFooter = true;
            this.gvState.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            gvState.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;   
            gvState.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        }
    }
}
```

> **GetAllSuppliers** contains all the data. It contains 8 fields & values from db and I don't want to show all these 8 fields and its
>   values but only 2 fields.

But whatever I have written in aspx page doesn't work. You can see that I used only name and email but it displays all the 8 columns from the database table.

> How can I limit this is asp.net page? As I don't have access to
>   database part and getting all the records.I use data table to display
>   data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need make AutoGenerateColumns false.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvState" runat="server" CssClass="gvdatatable" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Supplier_Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Supplier_Email" HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Columns.Visible` to hide them:

```
foreach (DataControlField dgc in gvState.Columns)
{
    if (!(dgc.HeaderText == "NAME") || !(dgc.HeaderText == "Email"))
    {
        dgc.Visible = false;
    }
}
```